# Prevent resizing container removing inner text

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="title">
        <h1>
            <span class="small-title">Test test</span>
            <div class="title-line"></div>
            <span class="animated-title"></span><span id="typing-cursor"></span>
        </h1>
    </div>
```

By removing all the text contained in a container (in this case contained in "animated-title"), the container disappears (as if its dimensions became 0.0) until the content is inserted again. This unfortunately causes the movement of all the elements contained inside the h1 container. I tried to set a "min-height", but the result doesn't change.
I also leave you the link of the codepen, but strangely on that site the container is not resized when the text is removed. [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Vallo92/pen/abdwovx)
Can anyone tell me how I can solve it?

Comment: You can add a `min-height` either on `.title` or `h1`. I've tried this and it works - [ https://codepen.io/ActiveCodex/pen/vYLZBZX ]

Comment: Okay, it worked! Unfortunately I was trying to insert "min-height" inside the wrong container ...